# how to overide background-color: #000000 !important;

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to override the `background-color: black !important` property on a WordPress project or delete that property but I can't find it in my CSS Files.

```
#top-nav > div > ul > li.current-menu-item, #top-nav > div > div > ul > li.current-menu-item, #top-nav > div > ul > li:hover, #top-nav > div > div > ul > li:hover, .top-nav-list > li > ul li:hover, .top-nav-list ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to include the rule you want after the rule you're trying to override.

CSS are, by definition, Cascading Style Sheets. That means that the following code:

```
.divwhatever { background-color: black; } // On WordPress Original File
.divwhatever { background-color: white; } // On WordPress Theme File
.divwhatever { background-color: red !important; } // On WordPress Child Theme
.divwhatever { background-color: orange ! important; } // On a specific File
```

In the end will be presented with a Orange background.

The last processed rule with always be applied unless there's a previous `!important` rule.

In that case, the last processed rule with the `!important` modifier will prevail.

**That's a very bad practice**: ideally you should find the original rule and change it or, at the very least, have no more than one `!important` statement for the same DOM model but I know how tough WordPress Themes can be to a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

you can override by creating mixin
`.test{background:red !important;} @mixin test{.test{background: blue !important;} }@include test();`